# Disable HTML escaping when converting Protobuf to JSON

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers

Given a simple Protobuf message

```
message MessageWithUrl {

  string url_params = 1;

}
```

I'm doing the following:

```
Msg.MessageWithUrl message = Msg.MessageWithUrl
                .newBuilder()
                .setUrlParams("?key=value")
                .build();

String json = JsonFormat.printer()
                .print(message);

System.out.println(json);
```

My expected outcome is:

```
{
  "urlParams": "?key=value"
}
```

Instead I get:

```
{
  "urlParams": "?key\u003dvalue"
}
```

I understand that the `printer` is using `Gson` under the hood, but I don't know how to have it accept the `Gson` option of `disableHtmlEscaping`